# Zend Framework - How to do custom redirect with the redirector helper?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to use the URL schemes in Zend Framework like /list?id=2&name=test, something like that, when I do redirection, I call this way: `$this->_helper->redirector('index','list','',array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'test'));`. But the URL generated will be /list/index/id/2/name/test which makes it inconsistent. How do I prepare a URL scheme like this without using custom routers (I have more than 10 controllers to do so...)?

Comment: Could you show please how do you solve this problem? I have the same task, but dont know how does own router look like.

Comment: http://pastie.org/1717136 That's what I have done, I just copied the original zend router, then made some changes at the parameters side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your bootstrap.php you can overwrite the default route

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$router = $front->getRouter();
$route = new My_New_Route( ... )
$router->addRoute('default', $route);
```

`$this->_helper->redirector` uses automatically the default routers assemble method.

Unfortunately there is no integrated router that formats URLs in the way you want (with ?parameter=value& ... instead of /parameter/value)

So if you want to change this, you can make a new class

`class MyRouter extends Zend_Controller_Router_Route`

and overwrite the assemble function.